# Redirect www.example.com/apple to food.example.com/fruits/apple

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect users from


`www.example.com/apple`


to


`http://food.example.com/fruits/apple`


**Note:**

1. This is a hardcoded redirection. Even a mapping if you will. "apple" will not be substituted with anything else. Nothing in the two URLs will change except for the domain of course. So there is no need for a regular expression to match the "apple" or anything else.
2. There is already dozens of RewriteCond and RewriteRule things in the .htaccess file. I do not want them to be affected. This redirection is independent of those.

I have access to the .htaccess file at the root of www.example.com and the httpd.conf

What code should I put in .htaccess in order to achieve this? Or should I change the httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
Redirect /apple http://food.example.com/fruits/apple
```

Comment: I didn't know about the "Redirect" keyword. Only had knowledge of RewriteCond and RewriteRule. It works thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

or maybe with a meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://foo.bar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers above are actually correct. However, I prefer the method of BvdVen since all contents of directory www.example.com/apple will be redirected to food.example.com/fruits/apple.

If you use the HTML meta redirect of Tronic, tendency is you will have to put this in all the html pages under /apple.

Also, for the unanswered question

> What code should I put in .htaccess in order to achieve this? Or should I change the httpd.conf?

I would suggest that you put it in httpd.conf if you have access to it. It is much more faster than having it in .htaccess. Why slow? You can read it from the Apache documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html#when

Hope this helps,
Ismael Casimpan :)